# How to pass class object as a reference to another header file's function

Tags: c++, oop

I have main.cpp

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Driver.h"

 int main(){
   Customer o_customer;        //Customer class object
   //ManageMenu is a Driver.h method
      ManageMenu( o_customer );   //calling method

  return 0;
}
```

My `Driver.h` is just a `.h` and `.cpp` file which does not have any class in it. What it does is handles all the screen display method, sample

```
#include "Customer.h"
void ManageMenu( Customer & customer );
```

and, here is the issue , I am not able to pass the object reference in this function and I also believe that it is valid too as it simply means that we are passing the reference to some function.

My `Driver.cpp`

```
#include "Driver.h"
void ManageMenu( Customer & customer ){
 //do something
   //calls the method of Customer's class
customer.AddDetails();

}
```

I am not able to pass the object, the error which I am getting in `g++` is

```
error: variable or field 'ManageMenu' declared void
error: 'Customer' was not declared in this scope
        'customer' was not declared in this scope
 void ManageMenu( Customer & customer );
```

Please help me out and do explain me where I am doing the mistake. THANKS!!

Comment: It's there , sorry I forget to mention here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Driver.cpp you forgot to add

```
#include "Customer.h"
```

Comment: What are you typing in the terminal to compile your program?

Comment: Yes.. I am using Linux

Comment: What is the command you are typing, something like `g++ <other stuff>`

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 Driver.h Driver.cpp Customer.h Customer.cpp Main.cpp -o M`. Well, I need to tell you one more thing, I am able to create `.o` file by using `g++ -std=c++11 -c Driver.h Driver.cpp`

Comment: Don't include header files when compiling programs. You're only supposed to include them. You're supposed to compile the .cpp files. So something like this `g++ Main.cpp Driver.cpp Customer.cpp -o M -std=c++11`